# Long Range Spin-Spin Interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spin-models

A recent [article](http://www.utexas.edu/news/2013/02/21/researchers-propose-new-way-to-probe-earths-deep-interior/) on probing Earth's interior mentioned the potential use of a "fifth force", long range electron spin-spin interactions, as a tool in the endeavor.
Has anybody published any experimental results confirming detection of this "force'? Is existence of long range spin-spin interaction compatible with current quantum mechanics theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this 
Many particle-physics models that extend the standard model predict the existence of long-range spin-spin interactions. We propose an approach that uses the Earth as a polarized spin source to investigate these interactions. Using recent deep-Earth geophysics and geochemistry results, we create a comprehensive map of electron polarization within the Earth induced by the geomagnetic field. We examine possible long-range interactions between these spin-polarized geoelectrons and the spin-polarized electrons and nucleons in three laboratory experiments. By combining our model and the results from these experiments, we establish bounds on torsion gravity and possible long-range spin-spin forces associated with the virtual exchange of either spin-one axial bosons or unparticles.

If you are not satisfied or it is wrong then forgive me and visit yhelink below
http://www.sciencemag.org/content/339/6122/928.full

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing would show up in experiments as a violation of the equivalence principle. There are strict upper limits on such effects (e.g., Heckel 2006, which used a spin-polarized torsion pendulum), and the Amherst-UT group also gets a null result. A positive result from such an experiment might be evidence for gravitational torsion, or, according to the Heckel paper, "Spin-dependent forces are also generically produced by the exchange of pseudoscalar particles."

Heckel, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0606218